# How to use 3rd-party libraries in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have a class handles some API integration that I would like to be made available in my main site bundle that looks like so:

```
class ACH {
  public function __constructor();
  public function addACHTransaction();
  ...
}
```

How do I integrate this class within Symfony 2 so that I can use it within my controllers and entities by doing something like:

```
$ach = new ACH();
```

**Edit: ** Here are the contents of my autoload.php file.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs');
}

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the Symfony [ClassLoader Component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html).

You may need to create a new wrapper Class in case your 3rd-party library doesn't follow symfony standards (i.e. use of namespaces). For sf2.0 take a look at this [blog article](http://www.kiwwito.com/article/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2).

**EDIT**: This [reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/113u8u/including_zend_1_in_symfony_21_finally_fixed_it/) explains how to deal with the `Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::registerPrefixes()` error. I haven't tested it but maybe the ClassLoader documentation is not up to date yet for sf2.1.

Add these lines in your `app/autoload.php` file:

```
$loader->add('foo_', __DIR__.'/../vendor/Foo/lib');
set_include_path(__DIR__.'/../vendor/Foo/lib'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow the instructions, but I'm not sure where to call $loader->registerPrefixes() in my autoload.php file as $loader has already been defined. I added my autoload.php file above.

Comment: Adding it immediately after   $loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';  should work.

Comment: It doesn't ... Fatal error: Call to undefined method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::registerPrefixes()

Comment: Sorry, last time I used ClassLoader it was on sf2.0 . Try adding it before $loader->register(); in /vendor/composer/autoload_real.php file instead.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. It can't find registerPrefixes().

Answer (score 1):

The [ClassLoader](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php) Composer uses is different from the `ClassLoader` Symfony provides. Try following,

```
$achMap = array(
    'ACH' => 'path/of/ACH.php'
);
$loader->addClassMap($achMap);
```